# Oracle APEX - setting a default value for a Popup LOV

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex21.2

I have a popup LOV on my page and it is populated via the shared component. What I want is when the underlying query pulls only one record, to have it pre-selected in the LOV by default. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Can it be done ? Most probably ;) I have not tested this but this is how it could be done:

1. Create a computation to set the page item to the value of the single row.
2. Add a condition to the the computation so it only fires if the query above returns a single row.

For the condition, one possibility is to use a type "rows returned" with a query like the one below:

```
WITH count_rows (cnt) AS
(
    select count(*) from (<your shared component query>)
)
SELECT 1 FROM count_rows WHERE cnt = 1;
```

Now, if you want to make this really dynamic you could write some code against  the view `APEX_APPLICATION_LOVS` to pull the query from the shared component and check if it only returns a single row. Note that in this case, whenever the shared component changes the code on your page might break.

Comment: If you want to limit the number of queries, another solution would be for a Dynamic Action to count the number of options rendered, and set the item only if one is present.

Comment: Correction - I was initially thinking about select lists. Popup LOVs are more dynamic, so you'd need Koen's approach.

Comment: what condition would I add check for the number of rows in the select list?